# Java type safety casting issue

Tags: java, casting

I've two classes as follows:

```
// Jackson annotated-class
public class User {

}
```

And:

```
// Jackson annotated-class
public class ResponseWrapper<ResultType> {
    ...
}
```

During a certain operation, I need to perform a cast.

- **Case 1:**

  ```
  ResponseWrapper<User> r = (ResponseWrapper<User>) result.getResult();
  ```

  **Warning:** `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ResponseWrapper<User>`
- **Case 2**:

  ```
  Object o = result.getResult();
  if ( o instanceof ReaponseWrapper<?> ) {
      ResponseWrapper<?> r = (ResponseWrapper<?>) result.getResult(); // OK
  }
  ```

  **No warning**.
- Case 3

  ```
  Object o = result.getResult();
  if ( o instanceof ResponseWrapper ) {
      ResponseWrapper<User> r = (ResponseWrapper<User>) result.getResult();
  }
  ```

  **Warning** (again): `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ResponseWrapper<User>`

How can I perform a type safety casting from `Object` to `ResponseWrapper<User>`?

Comment: I think you need to modify the return type of `getResult`. In my guess it is currently set to return `Object`.

Comment: In your case 3, shouldn't you be casting the `o` rather than calling `result.getResult()` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Generics are a compile-time help. At runtime, Java uses type erasure. Java thus can't check at runtime if your wrapper is a `ResponseWrapper<Foo>` or a `ResponseWrapper<Bar>`. All it can check is if it's a `ResponseWrapper`. That's why you get such a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use generics to declare `getResult`, like this:

```
public <T extends ResponseWrapper> T getResult() {
     ...
}
```

If the `getResult` method is from a library that you can't change, you won't be able to fix the warning.